# PHP not incresing session timeout

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, zend-framework

For several days I am trying to increase the session timeout for the admin area of a site. The staff have to login and very often losing all the data when they get interrupted by a phone call.

I cannot set the php.ini file higher as this site has thousands of users and the session folder would become massiv.

I have use .htaccess to set session time to one day. Checking with phpinfo() it shows the local value is 86400.
Using ini_get also returns 86400

But no file in the sessions folder is older then 25 min. 1440 sec from the standard php.ini

What else can I do to increase the session timeout for the admin folder?

Comment: Did you `session_set_cookie_params(86400);` inside the script too?

Comment: Try in htaccess:    **php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400**

Comment: @Starkeen I have already added php_value  session.gc_maxlifetime  86400 to the .htacces in the admin folder a few days ago

Comment: @syck I have not done that, will try that now. But the cookie is in the browser not in php? In the script I have added setExpirationSeconds(86400) as this is a Zend script. But that also made no change. I will add your suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear which php configurations you have modified to `86400`, but PHP sessions are tied to  multiple configuration directives that can effect a session's life time.

Since sessions are made up of two parts (*the cookie that lives on the client side, and the session file that lives on the server side*) there are two main values controlling each of their life times.

## The Session Cookie [Client]

The cookie is controlled by the [`session.cookie_lifetime`](http://php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) directive, which by default is set to `0`, meaning it expires as soon as the user closes their browser. This value should typically be greater than or at least equal to the `session_gc.maxlifetime` value.

## The Session File [Server]

The session file on the server is controlled by the [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) directive, which by default is set to `1440` *seconds* (which is 24 minutes). This the amount of time the server-side session can remain inactive before it is marked for garbage collection by PHP.

There are a number of other variables effecting garbage collection of server-side sessions, but primarily both the session life time and the cookie lifetime must be equal in order for the session to effectively last at least that long. Both directives are in number of seconds.

## Edge Cases

Finally, there is the off chance that you are using a patched up version of PHP (like those typically offered by Debian-based distros such as Ubuntu), which place their own garbage collection routine in their PHP package. This can be controlled by a system crontab that does its own garbage collection routine and may effectively change the stock PHP behavior unexpectedly.

## From the manual

> **Note:**
> If different scripts have different values of `session.gc_maxlifetime` but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with [`session.save_path`](http://php.net/session.configuration#ini.session.save-path).

Meaning that if you have multiple sessions residing in the same directory, with differing lifetime values, then it's likely the smallest lifetime will trigger the garbage collector to clean up those sessions. This is because the gc does not bother to distinguish sessions based on their varying configurations, but based on which session triggers the gc on a specific storage path (*then all the files exceeding the TTL are cleaned up regardless*).

So just put those sessions you want to have different lifetimes for in different directories by giving them a different `session.save_path` than the default sessions you typically want to last for a shorter time.

Comment: thanks for this info. Especially the info about multiple length session in the same directory help me in the end to get my problem fixed.